# How to fetch value store in SP.FieldLookupValue object

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to fetch value from the following SP.FieldLookupValue object ie $1E_1 storing value **"karanataka"**
output:

```
SP.FieldLookupValue
$1E_1:"KARNATAKA"
__proto__:Object
```

While debugging :

```
projectNumberLookup = SP.FieldLookupValue {$1E_1: "KARNATAKA"}
```

Following is my code example:

```
var projectNumberLookup = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
var projLookupId = listItemState;
projectNumberLookup.set_lookupId(projLookupId);
```

I tried to access that value using following:

```
 var s=projectNumberLookup.$1E_1;

 newItem.set_item('State',projectNumberLookup.$1E_1);
 newItem.set_item('State',projectNumberLookup.get_lookupValue ());
 newItem.set_item('State',projectNumberLookup.get_lookupId ());
```

Nothing worked.Can somebody suggest a solution

Comment: Would you please provide an update of this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use get_lookupValue and get_lookupId function like below to get value from lookup field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getLookUp, 'sp.js');
   var oListItem
  function getLookUp() 
    {

        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {

            var webSite = clientContext.get_web();

            var list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("NewList");

            oListItem = list.getItemById(1);

            clientContext.load(oListItem);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));

        }

    }
    function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        // for multiple value lookup field
        var multiplevaluelookup = oListItem.get_item("TabletopSessions");
        console.log(multiplevaluelookup);
        for(var i = 0;i < multiplevaluelookup.length;i++) 
        {
           console.log(multiplevaluelookup[i].get_lookupId()); 
           console.log(multiplevaluelookup[i].get_lookupValue()); 
         }

         //for single value lookup field

         var singlevaluelookup = oListItem.get_item("LookupSingleValue");
         console.log(singlevaluelookup.get_lookupId());
         console.log(singlevaluelookup.get_lookupValue());


       }



    function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {

        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }

    </script>
```

[image]